# RestTemplate.postForObject and Lists

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, resttemplate

Hi i want a client to consume a restfull webservice. I use springboot and the service return a JSON list with just ONE OBJECT.
I want to use postForObject Api of RestTemplate like this

```
ResponseEntity<List<RetrieveRichiestaResponseDto>> result = restTemplate.postForObject(
                uri,
                entity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<RetrieveRichiestaResponseDto>>() {});
```

Why it gives me this error

```
> The method postForObject(String, Object, Class<T>, Object...) in the
> type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String,
> HttpEntity<capture#3-of ?>, new  
> ParameterizedTypeReference<List<RetrieveRichiestaResponseDto>>(){})
```

Thx for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restTemplate.postForObject()` don't support `ParameterizedTypeReference<>`

Use `restTemplate.exchange()`

```
ResponseEntity<List<RetrieveRichiestaResponseDto>> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, 
       new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<RetrieveRichiestaResponseDto>>() {});
```

Comment: Ok i did also this way ( i did a system that i make a soap request and i obtain a response in soap from a restful webservice) but in another service without a list with exchange it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException only with post worked. Infact with exchange in this service i obtain a null again

Comment: I don't know what's the problem is there, but when you need to pass type reference you can use  exchange() its better way

Comment: @MarcoBozzola if this solution works then don't forget to accept it and do upvoting